# How i can print from more than one textfield after clicking the button just once in java

Tags: java, printing

My question is how I can print from more than one **JTextField in Java** **clicking the button once**.I can call the print method but from that i can print from the specific JTextField but i want to print from more than one JTextField after clicking the button just once.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? BTW, add action listener to the button and concatenate Texts from all `JTextFields`in one go. Or add them to an array then print out Text at each index...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Do you want to print the the text of multiple JTextFields to the console? Do you want to set the text of other JTextFields to equal the same text as one specific JTextField after clicking a button? Or do you want to be able to type in multiple JTextFields at the same time you are typing in one specific JTextField?

Comment: I want to print the text of multiple JTextFields to the console. @A.Cucci

Comment: Seems simple enough, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the texts from every textfields and add them in to another textfield or console.

Try this example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Example {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField trextField1;
    JTextField trextField2;
    JTextField trextField3;
    JTextField trextField4;
    JButton button;
    public Example() {
        execute();
    }

    public void execute(){
        frame = new JFrame("GridBag");
        frame.setSize(400,400);

        trextField1 = new JTextField("Hello");
        trextField2 = new JTextField("Friend");
        trextField3 = new JTextField("How r u");
        trextField4 = new JTextField("");
        trextField4.setSize(50, 10);

        panel= new JPanel();

        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        panel.setSize(400,400);

        panel.add(trextField1);
        panel.add(trextField2);
        panel.add(trextField3);
        panel.add(trextField4);

        button = new JButton("Say it");
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        buttonAction();
    }

    public void buttonPress(){
        //If you have lot of textfields you need to get values to array and iterate through them
        String s = trextField1.getText() + trextField2.getText() + trextField3.getText();
        trextField4.setText(s);

    }

    public void buttonAction(){
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                  buttonPress();
              }});
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Example g = new Example();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to print the text of multiple JTextFields to the console, all you really have to do is use the ".getText()" method for each JTextField. It would be best to create a method that does so.

An example using three JTextFields:

```
JTextfield txt1= new JTextField("Hello");
JTextfield txt2 = new JTextField("Hi");
JTextfield txt3 = new JTextField("Hey");
```

Create a method that gets and prints out the text of each textfield:

```
public void printAllTextFields() {
   System.out.println(txt1.getText());
   System.out.println(txt2.getText());
   System.out.println(txt3.getText());
}
```

Then just call this method whenever you need to in your program.

The output of this example would be:

```
Hello
Hi
Hey
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can just simply add

```
JTextField#.append([variable_here])
```

in the JButton Function that you are using and append that same data to multiple Text Field.

Comment: (1-) there is no append(...) method for a JTextField. Read the API.

Comment: Ahh my fault.

I used JTextArea.append() in my previous assignment. Got them mixed up. @camickr